# Почему Ajax-ответ от сервера, содержащий файл, приходит с неправильной кодировкой?

Tags: javascript, ajax, кодировка

Получаю файл (экспорт из админки) через ajax. На сервере он сохраняется в php://output, после чего устанавливается в content ответа вместе с Content-type и Content-Disposition (xlsx-файл). Для сохранения использую [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver).
Размер итогового Blob, как и файла, получается больше, чем приходит в ответе - к примеру, размер блоба 12446 байт, а от сервера пришло 7143 байт. Подозреваю, что причина в том, что браузер каким-то образом неправильно обрабатывает многобайтовую кодировку или бинарные данные, но как исправить?

Comment: А может просто потому что там gzip?

Comment: Нет, там напрямую отправляется содержимое файла без какого-либо сжатия

Comment: Какой Content-type вы поставили?